# Menu Item Binding WPF Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem with Menu Item Command Binding. I have used MVVM pattern 
When I use right click, the menu appears. But when I click on the menu item doesn't work. Do you know why? Thanks

Here is the XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="PlotView.ViewModel.PlotViewControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="600"
             x:Name="theViewName">

    <UserControl.Resources>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <GroupBox  Name="GB" Header="Graphs"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  BorderThickness="0">
        <ListView Name="PlotLista"    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedValue}" ItemsSource="{Binding PlotModelList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <oxy:Plot  MinHeight="260" Height="Auto"   IsRendering="True" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="8"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ActualWidth}"  Model="{Binding }">
                        <oxy:Plot.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Export to PNG" Command="{Binding DataContext.SavePNG, ElementName=theViewName}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </oxy:Plot.ContextMenu>
                    </oxy:Plot>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

Here are a small portion of ViewModel:

```
 #region Fields
        private readonly DelegateCommand _menuClick=new DelegateCommand(this.MenuItemClick);
  #endregion

  #region Command
 public ICommand SavePNG
 {
   get { return this._menuClick; }
 }
  #endregion

 private void MenuItemClick()
{
   // some code here
}
```

Error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'SavePNG' property not found on 'object' ''PlotModel'
>   (HashCode=15385318)'. BindingExpression:Path=SavePNG;
>   DataItem='PlotModel' (HashCode=15385318); target element is 'MenuItem'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: is SavePNG command on the same ViewModel which contains PlotModelList?

Comment: Yes.                                                                                                    public partial class PlotViewControl 
    {
        public PlotViewControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new PlotViewModel();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is trying to find `SavePNG` on your **Item**, not your ViewModel.

Instead, give your view an x:Name, or a Name, and use the following binding instead:

```
{Binding DataContext.SavePNG, ElementName=theViewName}
```

Comment: Ok but there is another problem .

Comment: Ok, what is the problem?

Comment: If I try to put the X:Name/Name , I get an error. Error 2 The type name 'ViewModel' does not exist in the type 'PlotView.PlotView' I am trying to add attribute to UserControl

Comment: Try this instead: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SavePNG}`

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SavePNG; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Can you provide the full XAML in your original question? I'd like to see what you're doing with x:Name/Name.

Comment: Just a little tip, ElementName bindings wont work on a ContextMenu as they are not part of the VisualTree of a control. So you when you ElementName = xxx, Context menu cannot 'see' that element. you use PlacementTarget instead to get the datacontext :)

Comment: I have put the  entire XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SaveCommand is on the same ViewModel which contains your collection.

ContextMenus are a little different in wpf as they are not part of the visual tree of the control. As such they cannot 'see' any elements by relative source or by elementnames.

A little cheat is to use the PlacementTarget property and get the datacontext with that. Change your ListView to below to make it work. Notice the tag property on the ListView and the DataContext property on the ContextMenu.

```
<ListView Name="PlotLista"    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedValue}" ItemsSource="{Binding PlotModelList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tag="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=theViewName}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <oxy:Plot  MinHeight="260" Height="Auto"   IsRendering="True" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="8"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ActualWidth}"  Model="{Binding }">
                        <oxy:Plot.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                <MenuItem Header="Export to PNG" Command="{Binding SavePNG}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </oxy:Plot.ContextMenu>
                    </oxy:Plot>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DataContext' property not found on 'object' ''PlotModel' (HashCode=54977229)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SavePNG; DataItem='PlotModel' (HashCode=54977229); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: @Adrian oops sorry remove the 'DataContext' from the menuitem, just use the command. See my updated code

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SavePNG' property not found on 'object' ''PlotModel' (HashCode=18762466)'. BindingExpression:Path=SavePNG; DataItem='PlotModel' (HashCode=18762466); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: I think you are doing something with your datacontext somewhere. Do you know how to use Snoop? It helps to find obvious errors sometimes. If you use Snoop to inspect your listview, check the Tag property and see it is showing the correct ViewModel

Comment: @Adrian also one suggestion, why can you not implement save command on the item viewmodel? Then you wont have any problem as such with datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't written in visual studio so please check the syntax:

```
  <ListView  Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext,ElementName=theViewName}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <oxy:Plot Tag="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}">
                    <oxy:Plot.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding SavePNG}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </oxy:Plot.ContextMenu>
                </oxy:Plot>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```